# How to represent the array of String in Entity Realtionship Diagram?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a database using PostgreSQL. I am using the Entity Relationship (ER) diagram. I have a table named LiCLSituation as shown in the Figure below, where I am using Circumstance as array of string. Is this a correct way of representation or is it possible to represent arrays in the ER diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a logical datamodel the array should be a separate table. It will have a foreign key referencing the table it is currently in.

In a physical model, from which DDL will be generated, showing it as an array is the right thing to do as this it the desired type for the column.

Neither is the "correct" representation. Each has a different purpose and is right for its own use.

Some modelling tools allow physical and logical representations to coexists in a single model and hold the mappings between them, some do not. If yours doesn't decide at what level you want to model and be consistent.

Comment: You mean I will create a separate table for array. But, In my database, I am using more than six arrays. Do I create six more tables?. For example, In PostgreSQL, I can use array of string like this:                                 CREATE LiCLSituation (
    Circumstance text[ ]
);

Comment: My answer specifically distinguishes between logical and physical models. For the *logical* I would diagram separate **entity types**. For the *physical* it would be acceptable to have **columns** of type array OR separate **tables**, your choice.

Comment: yes I am using ER diagram for the physical data modeling, which is required for schema level for creating a database. In this case, do I create a separate table for the user defined data type?. For example, In LiCLDataModel, I have created SFiC, LiCFLink and ReqInfoChunk data type. Do I create three table of their attributes.